# Is there a way to hide the menu bar is OS X when you are inside a certain program?

Tags: macos, menu, zsh

I know you can change in system prefs to show / hide, but what I want is to create a shell command that gets run with a certain program that will hide the menu bar when I am using that app.

With this script you can show/hide the menu bar, so maybe if there was something added on that specified it to only do this in, lets say, safari?

```
#!/usr/bin/env osascript

tell application "System Events"
    tell dock preferences to set autohide menu bar to not autohide menu bar
end tell
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env osascript

repeat while true
    delay 0.1
    set flag to frontmost of application "Safari"
    tell application "System Events"
        tell dock preferences to set autohide menu bar to flag
    end tell
end repeat
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work as intended. Is there a way of locking the window size in place of 'safari'? If I click out of safari the menu bar returns, once I go back in to safari the menu bar disappears again but the delay is slightly off so the safari frame edge resets to where the menu bar is.

Comment: On my MacOS BigSur, Safari stays at the same place. What do you mean ?

Comment: When the menu bar disappears I reframe safari so it fits the top edge, but then when I click to another program and back to safari the top edge goes back down to where it would be if the menu bar was still there, does that make sense?

Comment: When I click to another program and back to Safari, Safari is still at the very top of the screen. Which version of MacOS are you using ?

Comment: Im in Big Sur. Here is a video of me switching between applications, you can see the menu bar resize. Safari isn't the program I have the application set to, that was just for the sake of example.

https://imgur.com/cVWxWu8